# Select list text not changing when j-query button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML `select` list with height values as follows. When button `btn-change-height` clicked i want to change select value as 500 and text as `5'0"`. but text is not changing. why?

```
$("#btn-change-height").click(function() {
    $("#heightSelect1").val('5\' 0\"').change();  
});
```

```html
<select class="btn nav-height-select" id="heightSelect1" autocomplete="off">
    <option value="400">4' 0"</option>
    <option value="401">4' 1"</option>
    <option value="402">4' 2"</option>
    <option value="403">4' 3"</option>
    <option value="404">4' 4"</option>
    <option value="405">4' 5"</option>
    <option value="406">4' 6"</option>
    <option value="407">4' 7"</option>
    <option value="408">4' 8"</option>
    <option value="409">4' 9"</option>
    <option value="410" selected="selected">4'10"</option>
    <option value="411">4'11"</option>
    <option value="500">5' 0"</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `$("#heightSelect1").val("500")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use value of option to select it so your code should be :

```
$("#heightSelect1").val('500').change();
```

If you want to select option with text `5' 0"`.

Hope this helps.